# How will NPM/WebPack manage duplicate dependencies within various version ranges?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I have an app that depends on other packages, many of which have their own dependencies. My app may depend on `package@^1.0.0` while another package that my app depends on uses `package@^1.5.1`. When I compile the app for production, will I have the code from both packages as a part of it, or just `package@1.5.1` (the latest version within range)?

What about `package@1.0.0` (strict version) and `package@^1.5.1`?

---

Is my assumption that if my app depends on `package@^1.0.0` and one of its packages depends on `package@1.0.0` also this will not end up as the same package's code appearing twice in the production bundle. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how strict you get with the versions required and if they conflict. If they conflict, you definitely will end up with duplicates of those libraries in your final bundled JS file. I'm running into this now with the following package.json requirements:

`Main Project
 - main-ui-scaffolding-library
  - componentB-library @^1.3.0
 - specialty-component-library
  - componentB-library @1.2.0`

Now in my bundledJS file I am finding componentB-library twice in the source. Once @^1.3.0 and once @1.2.0. It's quite frustrating because the last one included is going to be the one that is referenced by the variable/angularjs component/service name. And based on how webpack decides to crawl your dependency tree, it's tough to really know which one is going to be the one that loads last.

Hope this helps!